# Find the position of a whole nested list if one of the values in that list contains an "Indeterminate" value

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to find the position of a whole nested list if one of the values in that list contains an "Indeterminate" value.

For example.

```
a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,Indeterminate},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}}
```

gives me

```
b = {2}
```

As the Indeterminate value is contained in the nested list at position 2 of a.

Comment: "Nested list" can comprise a quite broad range of expressions.  Do you mean a list of flat lists? Or is deeper nesting possible: `{{1,2,3},{4,5,Indeterminate},{7,{8,Indeterminate},9}}` --> `{{2}, {3,2}}`? And is that the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All-level function:

```
indetList = Position[#, {___, Indeterminate, ___}] &
```

Examples:

```
indetList[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}]
(*  {{2}}  *)

indetList[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, {8, Indeterminate}, 9}}]
(*  {{2}, {3, 2}}  *)

indetList[{
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, Indeterminate},
  {7, {8, Indeterminate}, Indeterminate}}]
(*  {{2}, {3, 2}, {3}}  *)
```

---

Level-one function:

```
indetElems = Pick[Range@Length@#, Not@*FreeQ[Indeterminate] /@ #] &
```

Examples:

```
indetElems[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}]
(*  {2}  *)

indetElems[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, {8, Indeterminate}, 
   9}}]
(*  {2, 3}  *)

indetElems[{
  {1, 2, 3},
  {4, 5, Indeterminate},
  {7, {8, Indeterminate}, Indeterminate}}]
(*  {2, 3}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, Indeterminate}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {13, 
    Indeterminate, 15}};

b = Position[a, _?(! FreeQ[#, Indeterminate] &), 1]

(* {{2}, {5}} *)

or

b = Position[a, _?(MemberQ[#, Indeterminate] &), 1]

(* {{2}, {5}} *)
```